# how to predict the real data by spark ml

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have train a model using spark ml(2.0.2_2.11), but how can I use this model to predict my data?
all the example in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#multinomial-logistic-regression just show how to predict the test data.
So, how to predict the real data which want to predict?

My data look like this:

```
509:2 5102:4 25909:1 31709:4 121905:19
800201:1
116005:4
800201:1
19109:1  21708:1 23208:1 49809:1 88609:1
800201:1
43505:7 106405:7
806:1 9305:1 52508:2
10705:6
1806:1 8406:1  35509:1 105409:1
800201:1
```

Comment: Model has a fit function

Comment: may be you mean transform()?

Comment: Fit to train. Maybe that's what I read wrong. Transform to predict?

Comment: yes, I have fit to train and get a model, how can I use this model to predict the data above?

Comment: I don't know what this data is... Can you show some Spark code?

Comment: You need to use `fit` to train the model and then use `transform` to predict on new data. If you can post the current code, should be able to show the exact steps needed next for the new data.